# ESPN API, how can I parse/display the JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Not a newbie to working with the API JSON data itself, as I can parse it in PHP rather easily. But I want to do it using jQuery to use in a personal project I'm working on. As you'll see in the code below, I am trying to do is grab each of the current day's games and display them in the body of the html, with each individual game wrapped in a div called "contentdiv". I just can't seem to get things to work... the object references appear to be correct in the `each`, but I can't get anything to return.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
      var url = "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/events/?apikey=xxxxxxx";
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data.contents[0].contents, function() {
          $('body').append('<div id="contentdiv">' + this.competitors[0].name + " " + "at" + " " + this.competitors[1].name + '</div>');
      });
    });
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a part of the response body I get when viewing the API response using a JSON editor:

```
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "contents": [
        {
          "uid": "10:340819123",
          "gameType": "1",
          "status": "Final",
          "statusType": "3",
          "competitors": [
            {
              "uid": "10:15",
              "logo": {
                "logoFormat": "scoreboard",
                "logo": "atl"
              },
              "record": "66-60",
              "location": "Atlanta",
              "color": "#002248",
              "name": "Braves",
              "score": "11",
              "winner": "true",
              "type": "team",
              "displayName": "Braves",
              "shortName": "ATL"
            },
            {
              "uid": "10:23",
              "logo": {
                "logoFormat": "scoreboard",
                "logo": "pit"
              },
              "record": "64-62",
              "location": "Pittsburgh",
              "color": "#111111",
              "name": "Pirates",
              "score": "3",
              "winner": "false",
              "type": "team",
              "displayName": "Pirates",
              "shortName": "PIT"
            }
          ],
          "sport": "mlb",
          "buttons": [
            {
              "text": "Recap",
              "link": {
                "type": "internal",
                "format": "gamecast",
                "defaultFormat": "",
                "uri": "mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819123&appsrc=sc",
                "deleteUri": "",
                "share": {
                  "text": "MLB:  FINAL - BRAVES 11 PIRATES 3 via @ScoreCenter",
                  "url": "http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819123"
                }
              },
              "type": "custom"
            },
            {
              "text": "Stats",
              "link": {
                "type": "internal",
                "format": "gamecast",
                "defaultFormat": "",
                "uri": "mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819123&appsrc=sc&gcSection=boxscore",
                "deleteUri": "",
                "share": {
                  "text": "MLB:  FINAL - BRAVES 11 PIRATES 3 via @ScoreCenter",
                  "url": "http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819123"
                }
              },
              "type": "custom"
            }
          ],
          "type": "team",
          "gameDate": "2014-08-19T23:05:00Z",
          "macro": {
            "type": "",
            "format": "macro",
            "defaultFormat": "",
            "uri": "sport=mlb&id=340819123",
            "deleteUri": ""
          },
          "share": {
            "text": "MLB:  FINAL - BRAVES 11 PIRATES 3 via @ScoreCenter",
            "url": "http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819123"
          },
          "tv": "ROOT",
          "omniture": {
            "sport": "mlb",
            "league": "mlb"
          },
          "macroHeader": "ATL @ PIT",
          "ads": {
            "site": "m.app.espn.us.sc.mlb",
            "zone": "events;"
          },
          "note": "Justin Upton homers and knocks in five runs to power the Braves to a sixth win in a row, and the Pirates suffer a seventh straight defeat. Pittsburgh's Andrew McCutchen goes 0-for-4 in his return from the DL."
        },
        {
          "uid": "10:340819122",
          "gameType": "1",
          "status": "Final",
          "statusType": "3",
          "competitors": [
            {
              "uid": "10:12",
              "logo": {
                "logoFormat": "scoreboard",
                "logo": "sea"
              },
              "record": "68-57",
              "location": "Seattle",
              "color": "#012a5b",
              "name": "Mariners",
              "score": "5",
              "winner": "true",
              "type": "team",
              "displayName": "Mariners",
              "shortName": "SEA"
            },
            {
              "uid": "10:22",
              "logo": {
                "logoFormat": "scoreboard",
                "logo": "phi"
              },
              "record": "55-71",
              "location": "Philadelphia",
              "color": "#be0011",
              "name": "Phillies",
              "score": "2",
              "winner": "false",
              "type": "team",
              "displayName": "Phillies",
              "shortName": "PHI"
            }
          ],
          "sport": "mlb",
          "buttons": [
            {
              "text": "Recap",
              "link": {
                "type": "internal",
                "format": "gamecast",
                "defaultFormat": "",
                "uri": "mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819122&appsrc=sc",
                "deleteUri": "",
                "share": {
                  "text": "MLB:  FINAL - MARINERS 5 PHILLIES 2 via @ScoreCenter",
                  "url": "http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819122"
                }
              },
              "type": "custom"
            },
            {
              "text": "Stats",
              "link": {
                "type": "internal",
                "format": "gamecast",
                "defaultFormat": "",
                "uri": "mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819122&appsrc=sc&gcSection=boxscore",
                "deleteUri": "",
                "share": {
                  "text": "MLB:  FINAL - MARINERS 5 PHILLIES 2 via @ScoreCenter",
                  "url": "http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819122"
                }
              },
              "type": "custom"
            }
          ],
          "type": "team",
          "gameDate": "2014-08-19T23:05:00Z",
          "macro": {
            "type": "",
            "format": "macro",
            "defaultFormat": "",
            "uri": "sport=mlb&id=340819122",
            "deleteUri": ""
          },
          "share": {
            "text": "MLB:  FINAL - MARINERS 5 PHILLIES 2 via @ScoreCenter",
            "url": "http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819122"
          },
          "tv": "CSN",
          "omniture": {
            "sport": "mlb",
            "league": "mlb"
          },
          "macroHeader": "SEA @ PHI",
          "ads": {
            "site": "m.app.espn.us.sc.mlb",
            "zone": "events;"
          },
          "note": "Hisashi Iwakuma fans a season-high 11 in eight scoreless innings to guide the Mariners to their 11th win in 14 games."
        },
        {
          "uid": "10:340819110",
          "gameType": "1",
          "status": "Final",
          "statusType": "3",
          "competitors": [
            {
              "uid": "10:18",
              "logo": {
                "logoFormat": "scoreboard",
                "logo": "hou"
              },
              "record": "53-73",
              "location": "Houston",
              "color": "#000000",
              "name": "Astros",
              "score": "7",
              "winner": "true",
              "type": "team",
              "displayName": "Astros",
              "shortName": "HOU"
            },
            {
              "uid": "10:10",
              "logo": {
                "logoFormat": "scoreboard",
                "logo": "nyy"
              },
              "record": "63-60",
              "location": "New York",
              "color": "#011739",
              "name": "Yankees",
              "score": "4",
              "winner": "false",
              "type": "team",
              "displayName": "Yankees",
              "shortName": "NYY"
            }
          ],
          "sport": "mlb",
          "buttons": [
            {
              "text": "Recap",
              "link": {
                "type": "internal",
                "format": "gamecast",
                "defaultFormat": "",
                "uri": "mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819110&appsrc=sc",
                "deleteUri": "",
                "share": {
                  "text": "MLB:  FINAL - ASTROS 7 YANKEES 4 via @ScoreCenter",
                  "url": "http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819110"
                }
              },
              "type": "custom"
            },
            {
              "text": "Stats",
              "link": {
                "type": "internal",
                "format": "gamecast",
                "defaultFormat": "",
                "uri": "mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819110&appsrc=sc&gcSection=boxscore",
                "deleteUri": "",
                "share": {
                  "text": "MLB:  FINAL - ASTROS 7 YANKEES 4 via @ScoreCenter",
                  "url": "http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819110"
                }
              },
              "type": "custom"
            }
          ],
          "type": "team",
          "gameDate": "2014-08-19T23:05:00Z",
          "macro": {
            "type": "",
            "format": "macro",
            "defaultFormat": "",
            "uri": "sport=mlb&id=340819110",
            "deleteUri": ""
          },
          "share": {
            "text": "MLB:  FINAL - ASTROS 7 YANKEES 4 via @ScoreCenter",
            "url": "http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/gamecast?gameId=340819110"
          },
          "tv": "WWOR",
          "omniture": {
            "sport": "mlb",
            "league": "mlb"
          },
          "macroHeader": "HOU @ NYY",
          "ads": {
            "site": "m.app.espn.us.sc.mlb",
            "zone": "events;"
          },
          "note": ""
        },
```

Comment: What's the issue? I don't see anything lining up with your use of `competitions`, but other than that, please provide details regarding *how* things are failing. Note also you could debug in the JavaScript console.

Comment: Apologies, I realized I was referencing a different API dataset after I posted the question. Edited to reference the correct info.

Comment: Since this is cross domain the data should be treated as jsonp. Is that built in to $.getJSON? (I typically use $.ajax when dealing with jsonp) 
Can you just add callback=? to your url?

Comment: And what's the issue?

Comment: @DaveNewton The issue is that I can't get things to work at all. In other words, I can't seem to get the expected output. Like I said in my question, the object references appear to be correct in the `each`, but I can't get anything to return. I also tried running things through the JavaScript console, but didn't find any errors. Would that dictate that there maybe really is a problem with how I'm referencing the array using `each`?

Comment: After testing it appears the ESPN api is only returning json and not jsonp. that is why you are able to see the result in a browser or using something on the server side, but not actually able to get the json using ajax.

Your best bet is to use a proxy of some sort that will get the data from the api and output it as json on the same domain or jsonp if calling cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

After testing it appears the ESPN api is only returning json and not jsonp. 
that is why you are able to see the result in a browser or using something on the server side, but not actually able to get the json using ajax.

Your best bet is to use a proxy of some sort that will get the data from the api and output it as json on the same domain or jsonp if calling cross-domain.

---

This is typically how you would handle a cross-domain get assuming jsonp is being returned:

```
// Example JSONP request with jQuery
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/events/",
data:{apikey: "xxxxxx",
    _accept: "application/json"},
type: 'GET',
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.contents[0].contents, function() {
      $('body').append('<div id="contentdiv">' + this.competitors[0].name + " " + "at"     + " " + this.competitors[1].name + '</div>');
  });
},
error: function() {
     // handle the error
}
});
```

Comment: I cleaned up some typos. unfortunately, ESPN has discontinued their public APIs so I cannot actually test.

Comment: OK, I've tested and still can't figure this out. I can't get things to display at all. That said, if you would like to test out the code for the answer you provided, I do have another link to the data that you could use. Try "http://scores.espn.go.com/allsports/scorecenter/v3/events?sport=mlb". There's no API key needed for this one.